# Wget: Unable to resolve host address 'google.com' in kali linux os

Tags: linux, wget, kali-linux

when I try to wget on Kali Linux OS, I get an error, for example the error is

```
--2019-03-25 08:22:32--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)...
failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘google.com’
```

Please help me solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to a command prompt and do an nslookup on the wget target node name, e.g., "nslookup (insert FQDN here)".  If nslookup is not installed, you may need to install the DNS utilities package.

nslookup should return either the IP address of the target node, or a fairly verbose error detailing why the lookup failed.

Case 1:  wget throws an error, nslookup does not:  Something fishy is going on if nslookup correctly resolves the IP address but wget claims it can not.  Please post a session log.

Case 2:  wget throws an error, nslookup does not:  There is an issue in DNS resolution in the host system that must be corrected before wget will work.

Answer (score 0):

first off, I don't think Kali is the best distro if you're a new user, it will give you many problems.

Regarding your question, can you ping 8.8.8.8 instead?

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too, i solved it by opening the file "resolved" on the directory /etc/network/if-up.d, and changed DNS=DNS on the script to DNS=8.8.8.8, after this it started working fine even after reboot.
Hope it helps

PS:Look at the picture below before editing the script, else if you mess up something, not my fault xD

[Picture of the script after changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WXoC.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).